# Scala: Working with Implicit Collisions

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Suppose you have a class `Foo` and two additional implicit classes:

```
implicit class RichFoo1(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
    def doSomething: Bar
}
implicit class RichFoo2(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
    def doSomething: Baz
}
```

Now, if a class has imported both `RichFoo1` and `RichFoo2`, it seems that there is a likelihood of a collision when `doSomething()` is called, and the compiler may complain due to the ordering between the imports of the two implicit classes and/or information about the relationship between `Bar` and `Baz`.

I'm considering a workaround in the manner of the following:

```
trait ConvertibleFromFoo[T] {
    def doSomething[T]: T
}    
implicit class RichFooAs(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
    def doSomething[T](implicit f: ConvertibleFromFoo[T]): T = f.doSomething
}
implicit val bar: ConvertibleFromBoo[Bar]
implicit val baz: ConvertibleFromBaz[Baz]
```

The idea would be that `foo.doSomething[Bar]` would (with a bit of code) do what `RichFoo1(foo).doSomething` would be doing, for example.

What would be the drawbacks with regards to this approach here, as opposed to, say, explicit ascription?

Related to this: when would it be appropriate to outright define an implicit conversion method over defining an implicit class?  That is:

```
implicit def toBar(foo: Foo): Bar
```

versus

```
implicit class RichFoo(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
    def toBar: Bar
}
```

(For example: `scala-java8-compat` uses the latter for converting between `Option` and `Optional`)

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are asking. Do you want a recommendation how to prioritise one conversion over the other?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to avoid cases where you can have both conversions exist simultaneously, preferably implicitly, without the compiler complaining about ambiguous implicits.  Alternately, if, due to the relationship between `Bar` and `Baz`, ambiguous implicits are unavoidable, finding a cheap suitable workaround (explicit value classes? case classes?)